# Execute a batch file from the sharepoint designer workflow?

Tags: 2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

is there a way to execute the batch(*.bat) file from a sharepoint designer workflow?

I've a specific column in the sharepoint list, a batch file should be executed  whenever the value of the field is changed. I just want to design a sharepoint designer workflow to be triggered whenever the value of the site column is changed and it should execute the batch file.

Or is there batter approach to follow?

Comment: What is the batch file doing?

Comment: it will pull the information from the sharepoint list and form a html page.

Comment: Is this for one particular list or any list where the Site Column appears?

Comment: its a single list in MOSS.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that you create a custom workflow activity to do the stuff instead of a batch file. Since your only gathering info from a list and producing a file this should be quite easy.

Comment: which one you prefer, a custom workflow or an item handler?

Comment: Custom Workflow Activity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231574.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT recommend allowing the executing of .bat or powershell scripts from a workflow activity.

In some respects, this is a very huge security hole - someone could very easily inject their own code into your batch/script file to execute after yours, and depending on the context of the script, could wreak havok on your farm.

Instead, I would go with Wictor's suggestion of a custom workflow activity to maximise security.

Answer (score -3):

My recommendation is to create a powershell script that runs as a scheduled task.  This powershell script will look for a change in a list value item (custom column).  When the column changes then the powershell script performs your action.
I hope that gets you going in the right direction,
Dan